# Controlling how Bootstrap orders columns / rows when resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am using Bootstrap to create a layout of elements. Specifically, I am creating a table of textboxes. The table element doesn't prove to be good enough when rescaling, so I would like to do it manually using the grid system of Bootstrap.

What I would really like is for the layout to be like this on desktop:

```
**A** *B* C D
**E** *F* G H
**I** *J* K L
**M** *N* O P
```

And on mobile for the first column to inherit the second column's elements, ie that every element from column 2 would move under column 1. Like this:

```
**A** C
**E** G 
**I** K
**M** O
*B* D
*F* H
*J* L
*N* P
```

Is there any way to do this in Bootstrap? I have searched but I don't think I have found anything relevant. Thanks

Comment: That's a shame, but at least it saves me time searching. Thank you!

Comment: My first instinct was "no" but on reflection you *might*...but you have to start with 
 two columns and when on mobile switch the order which *could* be done woth flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this could help:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 
 <div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-xs-12">A</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">E</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">I</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">M</div> 
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-xs-12">B</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">F</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">J</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">N</div> 
   </div>
  
  
  </div>

  
  <div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-xs-12">C</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">G</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">K</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">O</div> 
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-xs-12">D</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">H</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">L</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">P</div> 
   </div>
  
  
  </div>
  
  
 </div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```